# How to permanently set pip index url and host?

Tags: python, pip

I installed a new Python3.8 on my Ubuntu besides the original python 3.6 and 2.7 by installing from the python source package.

The Python3.8 is by default installed to /usr/local/bin/ and python3.6 is by default in /usr/bin. So now I can use pip3 and pip3.8 to access both versions. However one new issue arises after this installation. When I want to use pip3.8 install anything, I got this error message:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.douban.com/simple/six/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.douban.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/six/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement six (from versions: none)
```

pip3 (for python3.6 by default) isn't having this problem. So now in order to install anything with python3.8, I have to do this:

```
pip3.8 install xxx  --index-url http://pypi.douban.com/simple/   --trusted-host pypi.douban.com
```

Is there a way to permanently set up the --index-url and --trusted-host without using it for each installation?

Comment: You should recompile your Python with SSL support.

Comment: What's the option to do that?

Comment: Did you install the SSL dev package before compiling (`libssl-dev`)?

Comment: I didn't install SSL dev specifically for this installation. Do I need to do that? Is it not included in the ubuntu package by default?

Comment: just do `python3.8 -m pip install xxx`